# Can access port on public IP but not private

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, port-forwarding, port

I have a PC running a web server on port 8080, and SSHd running on port 22. In my router settings, I have forwarded port 8080 to 80, and set up an ANAME record on my domain pointing to the public IP. I am able to access my site on both my public IP port 80 and on my domain. However, I am not able to access the port using the private IP, or SSH into the PC. The PC has a static IP configured. How can I fix this?

Edit: per use request, the output of `ss -tulpn` on the server is:

```
Netid     State       Recv-Q      Send-Q                               Local Address:Port           Peer Address:Port     Process
tcp       LISTEN      0           128                                        0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*         users:(("sshd",pid=799,fd=5))
tcp       LISTEN      0           511                                              *:8443                      *:*         users:(("node",pid=1251,fd=21))
tcp       LISTEN      0           511                                              *:8080                      *:*         users:(("node",pid=1251,fd=20))
tcp       LISTEN      0           128                                           [::]:22                     [::]:*         users:(("sshd",pid=799,fd=7))
```

And the relevent output of `nmap -sV -Pn <server ip>` on the client is:

```
PORT     STATE  SERVICE         VERSION
22/tcp   open   ssh             OpenSSH 8.3 (protocol 2.0)
8080/tcp open   http            Node.js (Express middleware)
8443/tcp open   ssl/http        Node.js (Express middleware)
```

Edit: network sketch:
[image: network]
<sub>(source: [vectr.com](https://vectr.com/tmp/dYQlvcn06/caaVmgjXf.png?width=640&height=640&select=caaVmgjXfpage0))</sub>

Edit: additional issue, probably should have mentioned earlier: For a short time after booting up the server, I am able to interact with it. However, if I wait more than a few hours, or reboot my laptop, then the server appears dead to my computer.

Edit: Something weird: I set up a continuous ping on the server to the client (in fish, `ping <client> & disown`), and now I can access the server normally. Don't know what to make of this...

Comment: Sounds like a firewall issue.

Comment: @Appleoddity PC firewall, router firewall or something else?

Comment: Are you trying to access private IP address from within your private network of from outside?

Comment: I am accessing it from within my private network.

Comment: The firewall on the server.

Comment: The firewall on the server allows ports 8080 and 22 through. For what it's worth, pinging the public IP works fine, but pinging the server outputs "Host unreachable".

Comment: what you describe is not a common issue, and appears to have nothing to do with the port forwarding. so you have verified that the server and your host are on the same IP network, and use the same default gateway right? there aren't any VPN connections in play, right? can other systems on the lan see the server? can the server ping other machines? you didn't put the server in the router's DMZ did you? show us ifconfig/ipconfig from the server and the client, and describe your network layout (for instance are you using a switch between the routers and the clients?).

Comment: @FrankThomas I have verified that both are on the same network. There are no VPN connections in play; the server can ping the client and other machines. Both are using the same gateway.

Comment: (1) Do you mean by "private IP" the local IP on the local network and you are connecting from within this network? (2) What error are you getting? (3) What are the IPs of the server, the computer trying to connect and the local IP of the router? (4) Try using `telnet IP port` to connect and report on error if it arrives.

Comment: Please run ```ss -tulpn``` on your server and ```nmap -sV -Pn <private IP>``` on the client and append output of both commands to your question.

Comment: @dirdi I posted the output of both commands; see above.

Comment: @harrymc By private IP, I mean the local IP on the local network, which I am connecting from. The error I am getting is `Destination host unreachable`. The IP of the server is statically assigned, and the IP of the client uses DHCP. I have used `netcat` to connect to the server on the open port, and got the same error.

Comment: The two IP addresses may not belong on the same sub-network, which is why I asked for their IPs. This is typically the case when a node is unreachable.

Comment: Both are on the /24 subnet.

Comment: The nmap output showed that the client *can* connect to the server. Please try the `telnet <ip> 22`. You should see some OpenSSH server output.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned this in the question, will edit: For a short time after booting up the server, I am able to interact with it. However, if I wait more than a few hours, or reboot my laptop, then the server appears dead to my computer.

Comment: Weird. Have you checked if its IP has changed when that happens? Is it possible you have more than one DHCP server in your local network?

Comment: My client's IP has not changed, and the server IP is static.

Comment: This sounds quite impossible. You might need to recheck your assumptions.

Comment: @harrymc which assumptions in particular?

Comment: Every aspect mentioned in the comments and answers.

Comment: I ask once again: can you telnet to the server IP port 22 and give us note on what you see?

Comment: After rebooting, the output from telnet is:
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host

Comment: "No route to host" means your network is divided into two subnets. Will you finally disclose the involved IP addresses and the netmask(s)?

Comment: The static IP address of the server in this case is `192.168.0.82`, and the IP of the client uses DHCP. The netmasks for both are `255.255.255.0`.

Comment: And the IP of the client? Use `ipconfig` in CMD to find it.

Comment: The IP of the client is `192.168.0.96`.

Comment: Sounds like a conflicting IP address problem to me. Try using `arp` or `ip neigh` when the server is reachable and then again when it is not. If the mac addresses associated with its IP address differ, your DHCP server gave the same address to some other device. Is the static address of the server a static lease in the DHCP server or is it excluded from the address pool? Second thought, this would probably prevent the public IP address access as well. Are you on a cable or on Wi-Fi? What devices are between the client and the server? Routers/switches/APs...

Comment: @OndřejXichtSvětlík The server is on Wi-Fi (I couldn't figure out how to set up ethernet, as you've probably gathered networking is not my forte...), with a static lease set up on my router. The only device between client and server is my router.

Comment: How about client isolation then? Do you have it disabled?

Comment: ok could you show the output of nmcli on both server and client look to be something whit routes since you can connect from the outside but not from the inside if you do ping to the server locally what it say host unreachable ?  it does make ping ? if it do so, it is something whit the firewall which do you use firewalld ? iptables?

Comment: check like this fist ping the client from the server and then the server from the client if you don't get ping in any of that it is something on the network you should get ping in at least one ! if you don't as i say it is the local network and that could a bad configuration on the router

Comment: Please add output from the following to your question, from both server and client, once when the local connection is working, and again when the connection is not working. Do not obscure or censor this information, it can't be used to attack you and is important for us to help. 1) `arp -n`, 2) `ifconfig`, 3) `route -n`, 4) `ping -n ${other}` (where `${other}` is the server/client's IP as appropriate)

Comment: @Attie see latest edit.

Comment: @sugarfi - none of this information is included in your question... am I missing something?

Comment: @Attie see the accepted answer. (by the way, I pointed you to the latest edit only because I figured out the problem and as such no longer require assistance.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how this worked, but I spawned a separate process on the server, pinging the client, and now I am able to access the server normally.

Comment: This may suggest an ARP-type problem that is being hidden and isn't resolved. It's a very odd thing to need to do...

Comment: @Attie yeah... I think it either has to do with maintaining a connection between the two or one of the NICs going to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

For a standard router, the forwarding only works from the "outside", i.e. where the public IP lives. Therefore you cannot access from inside using the local IP and expected the forwarding to work.

[BTW: You wrote "forwarded 8080 to 80", but in fact it is the other way round, right? You forwarded 80 on the external IP to 8080 on your PC.]

For SSH to work from outside, you need to set up a similar port forwarding. Actually I would recommend to use a non-standard port on the external IP to (at least) reduce the number of attacks a bit.

Comment: I know that I cannot access non forwarded ports on my private IP. The problem is I cannot access ports 8080 or 22 on the private IP; all ports on the public IP work fine.

Comment: You cannot access the port from within the LAN via the private IP? Ok, but then this has nothing to do with the forwarding rules on the router - right? Sorry if I misunderstand your scenario, but it is not too easy to image without any network scetch or the like.

Comment: Not really sure what a network sketch is meant to look like, but I'll edit one into the  question.

Comment: Host unreachable from a ping? Assuming you got the right private IP, I would recommend to take a look into the firewall rules via `iptables -nL` and `iptables -t nat -nL`. What do you see?

Comment: On the server or client?

Comment: Well, let's look at both to be on the safe side..

Comment: neither of them have any rules under `INPUT` or `OUTPUT`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not access your site using public IP and domain name as per mention in question. because HTTP uses default port 80 for request and your webserver is running on port 8080. how it's working for you?

Also, you have forwarded 8080 to 80 via router and router forward request to port 80 on private IP, and none of the service running on port 80.

Might you have forwarded port 80 to 8080 and written opposite while typing question?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you are either not reaching the host or that the firewall on the server with static IP is filtering out the traffic.
Could you pleas print your (a) firewall tables on the server, (b) output of ping to the server and could you tell us if you are accessing using hostname or IP address. Please also post the network configuration (topology, gateways and IP addresses) of the sectiom betweem server and client.

Answer (score 0):

To me this sound s like one of two possibilities -

1. Server or Client PC has been configured to allow the NIC to sleep after a period of no activity
2. One of the two devices( server or client ) are configured to use DHCP and getting differing IP addresses.

Suggestion - Perform all three tasks below

1. confirm both devices have those respective NIC configured for STATIC IP
2. Configure STATIC Route (if needed)
3. Verify and configure as required so the nics used on each device are set not not use power saving modes and disallow sleep mode.

Best of luck.